# Can not get my code to update the GUI in javafx when dealing with a the circle class and increasing the radius

Tags: eclipse, animation, javafx

I have this code, and it's supposed to increase the size or decrease the size of the circle by changing the radius of the circle. My problem is that for some reason the circle is not updating when the radius is updated. The radius is updated but the Circle does not grow or shrink. Can anyone help me out? below is my code.

I have tried lots of things, but wound up getting more and more complicated with no successes.

```
public class Circle_GUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        CirclePane cp = new CirclePane();
        root.setCenter(new CirclePane());
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        Button btnEnlarge = new Button("Enlarge");
        btnEnlarge.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                cp.enlargeShrinkCircle(true);
                System.out.println("You have enlarged");
            }
        });
        Button btnShrink = new Button("Shrink");
        btnShrink.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                cp.enlargeShrinkCircle(false);
                System.out.println("You have shrunk");
            }
        });
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btnEnlarge, btnShrink);
        root.setBottom(hbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JFK=Event=Demo");
        stage.show();
    }
    class CirclePane extends StackPane {
        Circle circle = null;

        CirclePane() {
            circle = new Circle();
            circle.setRadius(100);
            circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            circle.setFill(Color.AQUA);
            this.getChildren().add(circle);

        }

        void enlargeShrinkCircle(boolean enlarge) {
            if (enlarge) {
                circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() + 10);
            } else {
                double r = circle.getRadius();
                r -= 10;
                if (r < 1.0) {
                    r = 1.0;
                }
                    circle.setRadius(r);
            }

        }
    }
```

I want the Circles size on the GUI to increase when I push the enlarge button and decrease when I push the shrink button.

Comment: Change `root.setCenter(new CirclePane());` to `root.setCenter(cp);`

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. I feel quite dumb now.